# How to get element attribute by xpath in pyppeteer

Tags: python-3.x, pyppeteer

I'm trying to use `ElementHandle.Jeval()` to get element `style` attribute through `Pyppeteer`. But the problem is I can only address the element by `xpath` since the element `class` is `dynamically generated`.

However, the `ElementHandle.Jeval()` requries `selector` as one of the parameters.

I've tried:

```
element = await iframe.Jx('//*[@id="root"]/main/div[1]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
style = await element[0].Jeval(pageFunction='node => node.getAttribute("style")')
```

It still requires selector. And I tried to find a way to `get selector` from the ElementHandle I addressed through xpath, but didn't find out a method allow me to do so.

and:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="root"]/main/div[1]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]'
style = await iframe.Jeval(xpath, pageFunction='node => node.getAttribute("style")')
-------------------------------
raise ElementHandleError('Evaluation failed: {}'.format(
pyppeteer.errors.ElementHandleError: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '//*[@id="root"]/main/div[1]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]' is not a valid selector.
at __pyppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:33
```

If anyone can figure this out, please let me know. Thanks.

-----------------update---------------

I figured out through editing the source code:

```
#!element_handle.py
# elementHandle = await self.querySelector(selector)
elementHandle = selector
if not elementHandle:
    raise ElementHandleError(
        f'Error: failed to find element matching selector "{selector}"'
    )
result = await self.executionContext.evaluate(
    pageFunction, elementHandle, *args)
await elementHandle.dispose()
return result
```

However, I don't want to do so. If anyone have a better way, let me know. Thanks.